# Wrong image path when running in a subdirectory of my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, path

I have a rails app running in a subdirectory, like `www.domain.com/sub`.
The problem is that if I set a image path in my css, like

```
/images/my_image.png
```

it breaks when I upload it to my server. I need to set

```
/sub/images/my_image.png
```

then it breaks in my development environment.
The same problem occurs in my .js files.

I read something about the `rails_relative_url_root` environment variable, but couldn't get it to work.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You could use URLs relative to the stylesheet. In your CSS, instead of this:

```
/images/my_image.png
```

Do:

```
../images/my_image.png
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on OSX you can set up passenger to mirror your production environment (put app in /sub folder) ... or you can look into less/sass ... I'haven't used  them much but I believe they might allow you set paths for assets programmatically